# On registration form , form fields are not getting saved in browser auto fill on submit .(ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, autofill

I have one registration form in my site in which I am saving fields and after saving the form when user again come back to that registration form I want previous field values to be saved in browser auto-fill.
below is my code snippet -

```
 <form class="clearfix">  
    <input autocomplete="given-name" name="firstName" type="text"  placeholder="Enter First Name" class="form-control" value="">
    <input autocomplete="family-name" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" class="form-control" value="">
    <input autocomplete="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control" value=""> 
    <input autocomplete="tel" name="phoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" class="form-control contactMask" value="">
    <input autocomplete="address-line1" name="addressLine1" type="text" placeholder="Street 1" class="form-control">
    <input autocomplete="address-line2" name="addressLine2" type="text" placeholder="Street 2" class="form-control" value="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" className="btn baseBtn primeBtn" onClick={this.signupUser}>Sign Up</a>
</form>
```

In this code onClick of anchor tag I am doing ajax call via signup user function.
and after that i want that users data to be auto filled in browsers autofill address in chrome.

- I have tried below ways : -

  1.Few people suggested to use form "submit" button functionality to save data in autofill rather than having ajax call form anchor tag onClick event.
  but that is also not working in my case.

  2.I have gone through few post in which they told to use proper name and autocomplete attribute for field. but by using that browser can only guess proper field values .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.
Actually,I just ignored that I am not directly submitting my form.
On backend we are using grails and using it just for REST API's.
on frontEnd we have react.js but request and response are getting served from Nginx .
So form is not getting submitted to grails that's why on form submit data was not getting saved in browser autofill.